# Kentico 8 Form Autosum fields

Tags: forms, kentico

I am using Kentico 8 built in forms.

I have various cost fields that I want to sum to create a grand total

eg. `$$input:cateringTotalCost$$  +  $$input:venueHireTotalCost$$ = grand total` field

What I have so far:

```
<td> align="right">$$input:trafficManagementTotalCost$$</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row" style="text-align: left;">First aid</th>
    <td> $$input:firstaidDetails$$</td>
    <td> $$input:firstaidTotalCost$$</td>
    <td>$$input:totalExpenditure$$</td>
```

with the $$input:totalExpenditure$$ field being autosummed for the other input fields

Can I do this and how do I?

Thanks

Comment: Did you actually try it?  Did you get any error?

Comment: I didn't try it as I am not sure how to.  I can't find a place to add it to the gui form builder and I don't know how to add it to the html code.  I used the form builder to create the fields then plugged them into dreamweaver so I could customise the layout of the form.  My code for the form is:

Comment: <td> align="right">$$input:trafficManagementTotalCost$$</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row" style="text-align: left;">First aid</th>
    <td> $$input:firstaidDetails$$</td>
    <td> $$input:firstaidTotalCost$$</td>
<td>$$input:totalExpenditure$$</td>

with the $$input:totalExpenditure$$ field being autosummed for the other input fields.

Comment: Please put your code in the question - not in comments.  It is very difficult to read it in the comments.

Comment: You could potentially use a [field without DB representation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Reference+-+Field+editor#Reference-Fieldeditor-Settingdefaultformfieldvaluesthroughmacros) and use a [macro](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Using+macros+with+forms) to calculate the total.

Comment: My apologies for not following posting protocol, as you can probably tell, fairly new and novice at this stuff.
Thank you for the feedback, field without DB rep sounds like a good idea, shall investigate further.
regards,

Comment: @rocky I don't think it's possible this way, since I think the user input values can't be accessed via macros ... only macro values available during the time the form is rendered are accessible.. user input data is not, if I remember correctly

Comment: thanks Boris, I will put that one to bed then.

Comment: @BorisP. Yes, that's right because macros are evaluated on server. If you need the total to be evaluated on client then a JavaScript approach as suggested by Plaz is a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a javascript to create an autosum functionality. Add a unique identificator to the each cell with input field and append a script tag with JS code like:

```
<table>
...
<tr>
    <td id="cateringCell">$$input:cateringTotalCost$$</td>
    <td id="venueHireCell">$$input:venueHireTotalCost$$</td>
    <td id="totalCell">$$input:grandTotal$$</td>
</tr>
...
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   var cateringInp = $('#cateringCell').find('input');
   var venueHireInp = $('#venueHireCell').find('input');
   var totalInp = $('#totalCell').find('input');

   var autoSumFunc = function() {
       //Plus add a code to test null/empty values
       totalInp.val(cateringInp.val() + venueHireInp.val());           
   };

   cateringInp.change(autoSumFunc);
   venueHireInp.change(autoSumFunc);

   autoSumFunc();
});
</script>
```

It assumes you have the jQuery library included :-) .

Comment: great!  I see what you are saying, shall give it a try.
much appreciated!